# Laravel namespaced controllers already in use

Tags: laravel

I have my `.api routes` and have namespaced my versions v1,v2, I have run `composer dump-autoload`.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2\ProductController;
```

**Prefix**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2'], function(){
    Route::get('products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('products/{product-type}', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('products/{product-type}/{product-sub-type}', [ProductController::class, 'subType']);
    Route::get('products/{product-type}/{product-sub-type}/{id}', [ServerController::class, 'show']);
});
```

Why do I get an error `Cannot use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2\ProductController as ProductController because the name is already in use` even though I've namespaced them?

Comment: They exist in different namespaces but have the same name. How is Laravel to know which one you’re referring to when you use ProductController? You need to give one or both of them a unique use alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2\ProductController as V2ProductController;
```

=> same controller name is not used.have to give another name using "as" that name used in Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2'], function(){
    Route::get('products', [V2ProductController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('products/{product-type}', [V2ProductController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('products/{product-type}/{product-sub-type}', [V2ProductController::class, 'subType']);
    Route::get('products/{product-type}/{product-sub-type}/{id}', [V2ProductController::class, 'show']);
});
```